# Hide/Display Flag in Highstock based on the range selection

Tags: range, show-hide, highcharts, flags

Is there a way to display flags in a Highstock chart only when the chart is zoomed in past a certain point (ex. the range is less than 3 months)?

If not, can the flags be set to only appear when the range-selector is set to a specific value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes) event and then use [addSeries()](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Chart.addSeries) to add flag series.